# Fairly Basic String Expansion in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that will take a 'compressed' string, for example

```
'a12b3c'
```

and return its 'expanded' form, which for this example would be

```
'aaaaaaaaaaaabbbc'
```

Each character is supposed to be repeated as many times as the following number or just one time if no number follows the character.

I have been able to create a function that will do this if the number values in the 'compressed' string are only single-digit numbers, so my attempt works for strings like

```
'a3b2c6'
```

but I can't seem to find a way to take into account the case where the number values are more than a single digit long.

Comment: Use regular expression

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Good questions usually include the work that you have done so far. You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35003123/edit) to include your code so others can assist you better.

Comment: Maybe explain what you mean with 'compressed' and 'expanded', or add the example function that you were able to create.

Comment: use some `while` loop to read more digits till you get some letter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> compressed = "a12b3c"
>>> expanded = ""
>>> for char, count in re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)?', compressed):
...     count = int(count or 1)
...     expanded += char*count
... 
>>> expanded
'aaaaaaaaaaaabbbc'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a oneliner with a generator expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'a12b3c'
>>> ''.join(x*int(y or 1) for x,y in re.findall('(\w)(\d*)', s))
'aaaaaaaaaaaabbbc'
```