# Splitting a string into groups of either a number and a letter or just a single letter

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to decode a string that looks like this "2a3bc" into "aabbbc" in Python. So the first thing I need to do is to split it up into a list with groups that make sense. In other words: `['2a','3b','c']`.

Essentially, match either (1) a number and a letter or (2) just a letter.

I've got this:

```
re.findall('\d+\S|\s', '2a3bc')
```

and it returns:

```
['2a', '3b']
```

So it's actually missing the `c`.

Perhaps my regex skills is lacking here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006949/python-expanding-a-string-of-variables-with-integers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003123/fairly-basic-string-expansion-in-python

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks, I never thought to use the word "expansion" or "expanding". But I did search for almost half an hour already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current expression could work with a small bugfix: `\S` is non-whitespace, while `\s` is whitespace. You're looking for non-whitespace in both cases, so you shouldn't use `\s` anywhere:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+\S|\S', '2a3bc')
['2a', '3b', 'c']
```

However, this expression could be shorter: instead of using `+` for one or more digits, use `*` for zero or more, since the group might not be preceded by any digits, and you can then get rid of the alternation.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d*\S', '2a3bc')
['2a', '3b', 'c']
```

Again, though, note that `\S` is simply non-whitespace - that includes letters, digits, and even punctuation. `\D`, non-digits, has a similar problem: it excludes digits, but includes punctuation. The shortest, clearest regex for this, then, would replace the `\S` with `\w`, which indicates alphanumeric characters:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d*\w', '2a3bc')
['2a', '3b', 'c']
```

Since the other character class in the group is already digits, this particular `\w` will only match letters.